# Db2 sqlcode -20186

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to run a simple insert statement in db2 but getting invalid statement:

my sql :

```
insert into schema1.table1 select * from schema2.table1
```

Error:

> SQLCODE = -20186, ERROR:  A CLAUSE SPECIFIED FOR THE DYNAMIC SQL;         STATEMENT BEING PROCESSED IS NOT VALID

I had gone through ibm knowledge center and found [this page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n20186.html).

I understand db2 allows 3 forms of insert:
There are three forms of this statement:

1. The INSERT via VALUES form is used to insert a single row into the table or view using the values provided or referenced.
2. The INSERT via SELECT form is used to insert one or more rows into the table or view using values from other tables, or views, or both.
3. The INSERT via FOR n ROWS form is used to insert multiple rows into the table or view using values provided or referenced.

My question is why db2 is looking for "for n rows" clause in my query.

Note: this query is being sent through SSGODBC.

Comment: Check the SQL that *reaches Db2*, as distinct from what you give to SSGODBC, in case SSGODBC is transforming the SQL in some way before submitting it to the Db2 engine. Also mention your Db2-server *operating system*(z/os, i-series, linux/unix/windows), and the Db2 version.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to try and explicitly state the columns.

```sql
INSERT INTO Schema1.table1 (col1,col2,...) SELECT col1,col2,... FROM Schema2.table2
```